# magento jQuery ui buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, magento

i have an issue with a template on magento i am trying to build.

i have created a basic magento template, based on the Yoast_Blank_Seo_Theme, demo store is http://shop.x11.us

on Chrome, all the top links work, where as on Firefox they don't do anything. neither does the add to cart buttons.

If you change the store to _store=en">http://shop.x11.us/index.php/?_store=en on Firefox, the links work fine. (this switches back to the default template)

if i remove the following from my local.xml:

```
        <block type="core/text" name="buttons.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
                    $j(function() {
                      $j(".button").button();
                    });
                    </script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
```

the links work fine, but then i don't get the button effect. how do i include correctly the jQuery buttons so that they work correctly?

any advice much appreciated

Comment: I didn't understand your apparoach. Why you used javascript code block in `local.xml`? You can put those functions in a javascript file than link `addJS` by local.xml file. Isn't so easy for you?

Comment: This will render the text inline (assuming that the parent renders it ). Benefits (?): one less http request, no need for extra template file.

Comment: Any ideas as to why this does not work on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Try validating your page at http://validator.w3.org/ and resolving the errors.
The problem seems to be with your html code:

```
<ul class="links">
    <button type="label" title="My Account" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <li class="first" >
            <span class="ui-button-text"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://shop.x11.us/index.php/customer/account/" title="My Account" >My Account</a></span>
        </li>
    </button>
    ...
```

I don't think it's valid to have anchor tags inside button elements. It's also invalid to have `<button>` elements directly under `<ul>` elements. Try restructuring you html like this:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li class="first" >
        <a rel="nofollow" href="http://shop.x11.us/index.php/customer/account/" title="My Account" >
            <button type="label" title="My Account" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">My Account</span>
            </button>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
```